# Как запустить вновь остановленный setTimeout?

Tags: settimeout, cleartimeout, javascript

```
if(notif == 1) clearTimeout(notif_check);
else {}

notif_check = setTimeout(function() {users.notifications()}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обернуть в функицю и вызвать повторно, или вот такой вариант:

```
var timeout = setTimeout.bind(null, function(){
      console.log('time');
}, 1000);
timeout();
```

и тоже вызывать повторно

Comment: Не самое лучшее решение, потому что метод bind не работает ниже IE9.

Answer (score 3):

Как еще один вариант, это объявить переменную, которая будет отвечать за выход из функции таймера с самого начала. Т.е. таймер-то будет работать, но функция - нет.

```
var stopTimer = false;

if(stop == 'da') {
    stopTimer = true;
}

var notif_check = setTimeout(function() {
    if(stopTimer) return;

    users.notifications()
}, 3000);
```

но я поддержу [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)